# How do you calculate multiple objects values in a list

Tags: python

I'm trying to add the sum of objects from a database but so far I have found no success

```
test = [{'shares': 5}, {'shares': 1}]
# print sum of the two shares (5+1=6)
```

I've tried to use `test['shares']` to print but it results in the error:

> list indices must be integers or slices, not str

I've tried `sum(test.value())`but creates the error

> 'list' object has no attribute 'values'

And `sum(test)`creates:

> unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'dict'

It seems like the objects are wrapped in a list but I do not know how to unwrap it?

Comment: Please note the conventions for formatting [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). See my edits please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One nice way would be

```
sum(x['shares'] for x in test)
```

Why does this work?

Given a dictionary `d = {'shares': 7}`, then to get the value `7`, you call `d['shares']`.

You want to do that for each dictionary in the list `test`, so you want to look at `x['shares']` for each `x` in `test`.

In Python, the function `sum` can accept something called a "generator expression", which is what we did here.

Comment: Thanks! Seems like this solves all my questions, especially given how there are so many shares in the database to process. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have a list of dictionary. You have to select the number of dictionary from the list and then use the key to access the value like that :

```
test[0]['shares']
```

Next time you can find it on internet easily ...

Answer (score 0):

`test` is a list. You want to access its elements by index:

```
print(test[0]['shares'] + test[1]['shares'])
```

Or, if you have many object in that list:

```
print(sum( x['shares'] for x in test ))
```

Or

```
s = 0;
for elm in test:
    s += elm['shares']
print(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are putting your data in a `list` and using it as dictionary better structure it like.

`{'shares': [5, 1]}`.

Comment: What to do :),  and also you can calculate the shares like `sum(map['shares'])`

Answer (score 0):

with below code you can some up all the object values even if its different

```
test = [{'shares': 5}, {'shares': 1}]

total = 0
for each in test:
  for i in each:
    total += each[i]

print(total)
```